# Using ActiveRouterLink directive is not working as aspected

Tags: angular, routes, angular-material, angular-components, routerlinkactive

This is the current router setup and it works fine.
this is a lazy loaded module under the path `search`

so the url's become as follows...
`search/all`
`search/web`
`search/guides`
`search/user`
`search/books`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: GlobalSearchComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'all'
      },
      { path: 'all', component: AllComponent },
      { path: 'web', component: WebComponent },
      { path: 'guides', component: GuidesComponent },
      { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
      { path: 'books', component: BooksComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

Now I got a request to get rid of ´/all´ and just have the url as `search` so I changed it into this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: GlobalSearchComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        // redirectTo: 'all' <--- removed
        component: AllComponent
        // pathMatch: 'full' <--- removing this does nothing..
      },
      //{ path: 'all', component: AllComponent },
      { path: 'web', component: WebComponent },
      { path: 'guides', component: GuidesComponent },
      { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
      { path: 'books', component: BooksComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

and it works... except that the routerLinkActive directive is not working as I expect it to..

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a
    *ngFor="let link of links"
    mat-tab-link
    routerLinkActive
    #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [routerLink]="[link.url]"
    [queryParams]="{ query: urlQueryParameter }"
    [active]="rla.isActive"
    >{{ link.title }}
  </a>
</nav>
```

`rla.isActive` is not working?

Comment: what is `[active]` ? is it doing anything?

Comment: @Andrei does it matter? :D this is actually mat-tab-link (forgot to add the property) so active will add a colored html element at the bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I found out that it was quite simple.
All that is needed is `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"`

Problem is that the route matches both `'/'` and it's children `'/*'`....

setting `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` is the same principle as `pathMatch: 'full'` in the routes config but for routerLinkActive

Hope this helps others :)